# fonts used in this template

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Here it is a latex template to create a thesis: [Latex Thesis Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis). I would know which font the author has used to create the text in various chapters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF Properties say "Pallatio", "Bera Sans Mono" and "Computer Modern", but it seems to me that CM is there only because it's LaTeX default, a brief look by me through the pages did not find it's appearance there.

You can get this information by looking into the Font Properties of the document, in Acrobat these can be found in `File -> Document Properties -> tab Fonts`.

Comment: it says "URW Palladio L" in my decrepit old reader; i.e., URW clone of palatino.  the computer modern stuff is probably all maths.